# Right font style and size for a master thesis

Tags: formatting, academic-writing

I'm writing a master thesis for my master in economics.

Given that the thesis is not expected to be too much formal (the master itslef is very practical and little theoretical) I want to use good conventions.

So far this is the formatting I used:

- main title "Thesis of ...": Arial 16pt
- Abstract subtitle: Times New Roman 12pt
- Abstract content: Times New Roman 11pt, justified
- Heading 1 (main sections of the paper): Arial 14 bold
- Heading 2 (sections of the paper, corresponding to Headings 1): Arial 12 bold
- Content of each sections (Headings 2):  Times New Roman 12pt justified . The content is starting after a blank line

How can I improve the formatting to make the paper looking professional?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your university have any guidelines or a favorite style guide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your academic department may have posted guidelines for this. For example, the Rutgers Graduate school has posted an [Electronic Thesis and Dissertation Style Guide](http://gsnb.rutgers.edu/academics/electronic-thesis-and-dissertation-style-guide), complete with sample pages. They suggest an easy-to-read font in 10-12 point type, but other schools may have different requirements.

Many schools may require that you use an existing style guide, such as [APA style](http://www.apastyle.org/), [MLA style](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/section/2/11/), or the [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html). These will probably be available for use in a local library.

Your school may use one of these, or it may have posted its own style guide, or use a hybrid of them. Check with your department website and your department advisor; they will be the final arbiter.

Comment: as far as I know there are no guidelines. I will send them an e-mail. I just wondered if there existed any good practice